# Salesforce DX nested LWC folder structure and different deployment methods result in different behaviour in sandbox

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, deployment, vs-code, project-structure

I have this nested lwc folder structure

```
--force-app
  -- main
    -- default
      -- lwc
        -- parent
          -- lwc
            -- child
```

When trying to deploy into my sandbox:

in vscode if I use  `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` to deploy a modified `child` component into my sandbox, the deployment gets done but I can't see the changes reflected in the org.

If I use `sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/lwc/parent/lwc/child/` it does not work either.

I only see the changes when I do a `sfdx force:source:convert` and `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy`, updates on `child` are reflected in the sandbox.

But If I go to the org browser in vscode, I can see `child` listed just below the `lwc` folder, so there is a 'lwc/parent' and 'lwc/child', If I retrieve source from Org then it gets retrieved into `force-app/main/default/lwc/child`  and if I modify that file and deployed with `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` or `sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/lwc/child/` then the changes are reflected.

So I guess that when it gets converted into metadata, all lwc would fall into a `lwc/component` kind of route as the [Salesforce DX Project Structure and Source Format Documentation says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm#:%7E:text=package%20directory%3E%20directory.-,Lightning,-Web%20Components). Deploy it into `lwc/component/lwc/component` just wont work

Is there a way to use `sfdx force:source:deploy` or vscode `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` to actually see the changes without doing a full deployment? or is it just a wrong folder structure? It does work when converting it to metadata though, so what's is really happening there? (beside my assumptions from the above paragraph).  Thanks!

PS: this is a big project and it's not that easy to "change the structure", it's a possibility, but I would recommend not to give me that answer, I understand that changing the structure and leave child in default lwc folder would work, but nesting lwc folders help us maintain a bit of an order and as I said earlier, it does work with a metadata deployment, so i'm keen to understand why that is happening

Comment: Just to explain a bit further, since it wasn't mentioned, is that the `lwc/componentName` becomes the root for the entire component. You can have other folders inside it to organize a component's scripts and resources internally, which are, I believe, flattened upon deployment/compilation. So, `lwc/parent/lwc/child/child.js` would create a `child.js` in the `parent` component that you could use to import from, e.g. `import someMethod from './child.js'`.

Comment: Cool, thanks it's a good clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because it isn't supported to have components in sub-folders under `lwc`.

The documentation you linked, [Salesforce DX Project Structure and Source Format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm#:%7E:text=package%20directory%3E%20directory.-,Lightning,-Web%20Components), notes

> Lightning web components **must reside in a directory named lwc** under the  directory.

The components themselves must be under `lwc`. Anything under the first `lwc` will be considered a lightning web component and is put under the `c:` namespace.

The best you can do, *which probably doesn't really help your goal*, is creating multiple package directories

- `force-app/parents/main/default/lwc`
- `force-app/children/main/default/lwc`

Unfortunately, there is no answer to give you that doesn't involve saying you can't do what you're trying to do.

You can see [issues](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1190) have been opened against the CLI (example with [aura](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1358)) and it's been re-iterated that LWC needs to be the direct child of the `/lwc` folder.

> all component bundles should be the direct child of the /lwc folder.
>
> ✅ lwc/myComponent
>
> ❌ lwc/subfolder/MyComponent

Comment: Good enough for me, Thanks!